# how to change datasource dynamically based on user input in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i have a usecase where the user will provide the database details ie url,username,password and db type (postgres, ms sql, oracle) using a setup form and i need to use that details and establish connection to the database. previous i used to use eclipselink where i used to create entitymanager using the database details now i want to use Spring data jpa to achieve the same functionality.

In jpa datasource object is created using the properties given in application.properties file but i dont want jpa to create datasource using database details from properties file instead the datasource should be created using the details given by user in runtime.

i have tried to created a bean which creates the datasource object

```
@Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public DataSource userDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                "org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tenant1");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("postgres");

        return dataSource;
    }
```